# MySQL to MySQL data copy in scriptella

Tags: mysql, xml, scriptella

I m trying to use a scriptella script to transfer some data to data in one server to another.
The script looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>
           test script
    </description>

                    <properties>
                            <include href="../config/kpoint-etl.properties"/>
                    </properties>

                    <connection id="in" driver="${driver}" url="${url}" user="${user}" password="${password}">

                    </connection>

                    <connection id="out" driver="${driver}" url="${url2}" user="${user}" password="${password}">

                    </connection>

    <query connection-id="in">
            SELECT owner_name, owner_domain, DATE(time_last_update)
            as pdate, count(*) as avg from kapsule where DATE(time_last_update)="2013-06-19" group by owner_name;

            <script connection-id="out">
                    UPDATE test SET username=?owner_name, domain=?owner_domain, frequency=?avg, rdate=?pdate;
            </script>
    </query>
</etl>
```

the 'in' connection id seems to be working fine, but on connection to the second server it shows the following error.

```
JDBC provider exception: Unable to obtain 
connection for URL jdbc:/mysql://localhost:3306/leopard
Error codes: [08001, 0]

Driver exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable
driver found for jdbc:/mysql://localhost:3306/leopard
```

The properties file is something like this

```
driver=mysql
url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.72:3306/leopard
user=leopard
password=user12
url2=jdbc:/mysql://localhost:3306/leopard
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

P.s. Do ask for any doubts regarding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra slash in the second url `jdbc:/mysql`. Try removing it.